# Jquery: Infinite scrolling of a table

Tags: jquery, scroll, html-table

In my Jquery Script I am removing the first row and adding it to the bottom of the table in an infinite loop, if table is longer than the browser window. '#usertable' is the id of my table. Other than that, it is a normal HTML table:

```
("<table id="usertable"><tr><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr></table>

$(function() {
function appendFirstRow() {
    $('#usertable').append($('#usertable tr:first'));

    setTimeout(function() {
        appendFirstRow();
    }, 1500);
}

function checkScrollBar() {
    var hContent = $('#usertable').height();
    var hWindow = $(window).height();

    if(hContent > hWindow) { 
        return true;    
    }

    return false;
}

if (checkScrollBar()) {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);

    appendFirstRow();
}
});
```

I want this to happen a little bit smoother so it looks like the page is constantly scrolling through an infinite page. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You want a smooth infinite scrolling so you probably want to use callbacks to start the new scroll.
No guarantee for syntax correctness:

```
$(function() {
    function checkScrollBar() {
        var hContent = $('#usertable').height();
        var hWindow = $(window).height();

        if(hContent > hWindow) { 
            return true;    
        }

        return false;
    }

    var scroll = function ()
    {
        //if there is enough space, replace the element
        if($(window).scrollTop() > $('#usertable tr:first').height())
        {
            $('#usertable').append($('#usertable tr:first'));
            $(window).scrollTop( $(window).scrollTop() - $('#usertable tr:first').height())
        }

        //otherwise, just scroll a little
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 300 }, { duration: 300, complete: scroll});
    }

    if (checkScrollBar()) {
        scroll();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that doesn't look really smooth at all. The page is scrolling, that's good, but first it scrolls down and than loads the new element. So the scrolling stops ever 300 ms.

Comment: And why are always two elements appended at the same time?